# SQL minus 2 columns - with null values

Tags: sql

I have this table (made from a SQL query):

```
Row 1 Row 2 
2     1    
3     NULL
```

And I want to minus the 2 columns, so I just select like this:

```
Select Row1 - Row2
From table
```

But then I get this result:

```
1
NULL
```

instead of:

```
1
3
```

How can I make it possible to get the last result?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Please try:

```
SELECT ISNULL([Row 1], 0) - ISNULL([Row 2], 0) from YourTable
```

For more Information visit **[ISNULL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)**

Answer (score 6):

The reason you got this is because **Any Mathematical operation with NULL produces NULL** So while doing operation all values should be read as **NULL=0**.

With **[ISNULL()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)**

Hence

```
SELECT ISNULL([Row 1], 0) - ISNULL([Row 2], 0) from YourTable
```

Answer (score 1):

The MySQL equivalent of [ISNULL](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx) is [IFNULL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull)

> If expr1 is not NULL, IFNULL() returns expr1; otherwise it returns
>   expr2.

Maybe also look at [SQL NULL Functions](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_isnull.asp)

[The ISNULL from MySQL is used to check if a value is null](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/comparison-operators.html#function_isnull)

> If expr is NULL, ISNULL() returns 1, otherwise it returns 0.

Answer (score 1):

in sql anything minus with NULL then it is always NULL so you need to convert NULL to Zero

```
SELECT ISNULL(ROW1,0)-ISNULL(ROW2,0) FROM YOUR_TABLE
```

Comment: The answers above with the [] didn't work for me. I also changed "ISNULL" to "IFNULL".

Answer (score 1):

Select Row1 - COALESCE(Row2,0)
From table

Comment: this is what worked with SQLite